# How to share posts and deep link to my android app

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to implement deep linking in my Android app, so far I can post to my wall but only posts that are really links that goes to google.com (obviously this is a test link). I want the user to be navigated to my app when clicking on the post through the Facebook app, please I need a step by step guide as am not that old in android programming. Here's my code:

```
private void sharePost() {
        // code for sharing the post on facebook
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS));

        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("name", "JSON Twitter");
        postParams.putString("app_name", "JSON Twitter");
        postParams.putString("package", "com.example.jsontwitter");
        postParams.putString("url", "com.example.jsontwitter");
        postParams.putString("caption", "Hello, anyone there ?!");
        postParams.putString("description", "This is a description");
        postParams.putString("link", "https://google.com");
        postParams.putString("class", "com.example.jsontwitter.MainActivity");

         new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams,
         HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {
         public void onCompleted(Response response) {
         /* handle the result */

         }
         }).executeAsync();
    }
```

Comment: You should use App Links. You can find information here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#linking

Answer (score 0):

One facebook status callback implemetation needed

private Session.StatusCallback mFBStatuscallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

Then i dont know what permission you have give.
But the permission i gave was

```
    private static final List<String> PERMISSION = Arrays
        .asList("publish_actions","publish_stream");
```

new permission request 
 set the default audience and the send the callback object(mFBStatuscallback)

```
Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                        (Activity) mCtx, PERMISSION).setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS)
                        .setRequestCode(100).setCallback(mFBStatuscallback);
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
```

And rest all same as your's. I hope it will work.

**Note** If you keep pressing on post button for many time only one time the message gets posted. After that it takes some interval to post another message. Its a default behavior of facebook

Comment: Nope, that's not working either, I have the permissions as publish_actions, added yours now. But still not working, and I've checked my app dashboard on Facebook, deep linking is enabled for this app and it can be launched via Facebook app.

Comment: when you press post button default facebook dialog pops up requesting for the permission for the first time ?

Comment: there might be 2 possibilities

Comment: there might be 2 possibilities  **Case 1)** problem might be with you keyhash. The keyhash u have given in the site doesnt match with keyhash ur app generates. that time it shows only the dialog but doesnt allow you to post anything on your wall.. But as you said u r able to retrieve user information with your app this may not be the situation. **Case 2)** parameter you are passing might be wrong try posting some simple message.

Comment: I have posted a link successfully, but my problem is with android-based redirection through intents, i've been stuck for about a week or so on this one, the documentation is poorly written on the official Facebook site.